# Is there a way to continue background processes even when device is locked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently developing app that is 2 part:

- 1st part is truck driving app that drivers take with them when making deliveries to read order info's and such (they are using tablets that run android)
- 2nd part is monitoring app for managers to monitor statuses of deliveries and such (they are using computers)

I want to implement GPS tracking now on both sides. I know I can get Lat and Len of drivers and wrap it into setInterval to get (for example) every 3 secs, like so:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
}, 3000);

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

My only issue here is will this process persist if drivers lock their phones or even minimize browser. 
Over all, is this good solution?

Comment: I recommend getting rid of all tags except "javascript" (because they have little to do with this), and *add* the one for the platform you're using (Cordova? Html5? Or...?)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed them now.